# Call function in useEffect only after previous are finished

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have useEffect in my file in this format

```
    useEffect(() => {
     async function func1(){
                    //fetching data from database storing it in variable
        const options = {
                  headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-type": "application/json",
                  },
                };
        
                fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_DB_URI + "/icty/" + setzip, options)
                  .then((res) => res.json())
                  .then(
                    (result) => {
        ..... setAddressCurrent(result)
        
                }
              
                async function func2 (){
                     if (user.address) {
                  const data = user.address;
                  let zip;
                  var bar = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key, index, array) {
                      if (data[key].types) {
                        data[key].types.forEach((x) => {
                          if (x === "route") {
                            Cookies.set("street", data[key]["long_name"]);              
                          }
                          if (x === "street_number") {
                            Cookies.set("street_number", data[key]["long_name"]);
                          }
                          
                        });
                      }
                    });
                  }); 
               if(addressCurrent === user.address) return 1;
                  return bar.then(() => {
                    return zip;
                  });
                }
                }
        
               
                func1()
                func2() //------> how to call this one after func1 is finished doing all job
            }, []);
```

Because of the problem func2 is called before func1 is finished I have undefined variables.
Anyone idea how to easly solve this in React Hooks?
Edited code

Comment: since these return promises, you'd need to use `func1().then(() => func2())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are expecting the func2 to be executed with the component state in the same hook execution, and you can't be certain that the state gets updated before calling func2.

Your logic is presented as:

```
func1() ==> sets state
<you expect the state to be updated for func2>
func2() ==> uses state
```

Instead, you should present your logic as follows.

```
useEffect(() => {
 async function func1() { /* function body that changes stateUpdatedByFunc1 */ }

 func1()
}, []) // only executes on component mounting phase

useEffect(() => { 
 async function func2()  { /* function body that depends on stateUpdatedByFunc1 */ }

 if (stateUpdatedByFunc1) {
  func2() // only call func2 if the state is not undefined or null
 }
},[stateUpdatedByFunc1]) // this gets executed after updating the state
```

Also, remember to put `await` everywhere you expect something to take time. For example, you are not using `await fetch(...)` and that certainly makes the `func1` return before you are expecting it to.

Comment: that's right,and where should I call func1() to automatically start?

Comment: Inside another hook, for example useEffect(() => { /* calls func1 }, []), which only executes when the component mounts.

Comment: Could you please add it to the answer, so I can accept it

Comment: Added! I also completed more bits on the definitions and such

Answer (score 0):

You cant run async code inside a react hook, you need to outsource the function outside of the effect and use async there

```
async function runFunction() {
    function func1 (){
        //do something here
    }

    function func2(){
        //do some stuff here
    }

    await func1()
    await func2() //------> how to call this one after func1 is finished doing all job
}
 

useEffect(() => {
   runFunction()
}, []);
```

Comment: unfortunately still func2 is called before func1 in func1 there is a lot of fetching data and setting it,after I set it, I call func2 and have error variable undefined

Comment: @HardRock What variable is undefined in func2?

Comment: Dear @Shmili Breuer I modifed a little bit code, problem is when I am setting variable and that setted one calling in function2, it is not defined